# Geometry nodes - lock distributed position in animation

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I have the following setup:

- A plane with an ocean modifier.
- A sphere scattered across this plane using geometry-nodes, with its Z coordinate aligned to the surface of the ocean. In other words, the spheres are "riding the waves".
- The "Time" attribute of the ocean is animated.

When playing the animation, I get the following problem:
[image: Spheres changing XY position along with animation]

The spheres are changing their distribution because the plane's mesh is deforming. I want to lock the spheres' XY positions, leaving the Z free to align with the waves.

This is the geometry-nodes setup for the ocean:
[image: Waves geometry-nodes setup]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Solved it with hair particles. Guess geometry-nodes isn't the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that *Geometry Nodes* are the "wrong" tool here.

You would just have to set it up a little differently:

- Just create a grid above the ocean, and distribute your points there. This grid should be placed above the highest wave.
- Then use the node `Raycast` and the *Hit Position* generated by it for your *Z-Offset*.

In addition, the node also provides you with the *normals*, which you can then use for a rotation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of Blender were you using for this as I get different results using 2.93.0 Alpha - I get a small number of particles popping in and out of existence as the surface moves but most of them stick with the surface as the ocean modifier distorts it. Also, I note that the Join Geometry node in your example has two separate input nodes but the 2.93.0 Alpha version has a single "multi-input" input node, showing you're likely on an earlier version.

Since the Geometry Nodes feature is still under development, I'd suggest re-trying with the latest version and seeing if this improves the situation.

Comment: I'm using 2.92.0. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try the latest version.